# Video file not opening in VLC

Tags: vlc

When I opened a video file, I got this error:

```
VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
```

The video file was downloaded from torrentz and had a `.exe` extension to my surprise.

Comment: Ok and your question would be?

Comment: If it is an `exe`, wouldn't you be suspicious that it was malware and, particularly, a virus???

Comment: Ya i was suspicious but file size was more than 1 GB

Answer (score 1):

VLC does not know which demultiplexer / decoder / etc. plugins to load in order to process the video. You can use `hexdump` to take a look inside the first bytes of the file. Maybe then you can find out if there is some multimedia content in it:

```
hexdump -C video.exe | head -30
```

this will print first 30 lines of `hexdump` to the screen. Most multimedia container like MP4 or AVI have some ASCII info at the beginning of the file. So in case you have an MP4 you will see some `ftyp, moov, moof, mvhd, ... etc.` like this:

```
00000000  00 00 00 1c 66 74 79 70  64 61 73 68 00 00 00 00  |....ftypdash....|
00000010  69 73 6f 36 61 76 63 31  6d 70 34 31 00 00 02 84  |iso6avc1mp41....|
00000020  6d 6f 6f 76 00 00 00 6c  6d 76 68 64 00 00 00 00  |moov...lmvhd....|
```

in case of AVI you will see something like this:

```
00000000  52 49 46 46 12 20 6f 00  41 56 49 20 4c 49 53 54  |RIFF. o.AVI LIST|
00000010  34 12 00 00 68 64 72 6c  61 76 69 68 38 00 00 00  |4...hdrlavih8...|
00000020  6a 04 01 00 a8 61 00 00  00 00 00 00 10 09 00 00  |j....a..........|
```

and so on. But probably you just downloaded some windows executable and there is no video related content in it. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It may be a windows exe which was downloaded.